# 'Multiplicative' paths in group algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, curves

Let $\mathbb{C}[G]$ be the group algebra of the finite group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$. We could consider what happens when considering paths in this vector space, but this doesn't seem too interesting. Instead, we could consider `multiplicative' paths instead.

As an example, take two (for the moment) invertible elements $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. Since they are both invertible, there exists some $\beta$ such that $\alpha_2 = \beta \alpha_1$. (Under some assumptions) we could split up the $\beta$ into a product of multiple elements $\beta_i \in \mathbb{C}[G]$, so that $\alpha_2 = \left(\Pi_i\beta_i\right) \alpha_1$. By taking the limit of a continuous product and taking all $\beta_i$ to be infinitesimally close to the identity element $1e$, we should now be able to parametrize `multiplicative' paths in our space.

My first question is, is the above well-defined? In particular if none of the $\beta_i$ become non-invertible. Secondly, have these type of paths been analyzed before? They seem to have some nice properties. For example, consider the function $\phi(\alpha) = \mathrm{Det}(\rho(\alpha))$, where $\rho$ is the regular representation of $G$. Then we have that for the path given by $\Pi_{t}\beta(t)$ that

$$\phi(\Pi_{t}\beta(t))\alpha_1 = \phi(\Pi_{t}\beta(t))\alpha_1\\
\rightarrow \phi(\Pi_{t}\beta(t)) = \phi(\beta) = \frac{\phi(\alpha_2)}{\phi(\alpha_1)}.$$

That is, the value of $\phi(\beta(t))$ is independent of the path itself, only on its beginning and endpoints (one should be careful here with crossing over elements that are non-invertible, but I guess one could make sense out of these cases using a form of the Cauchy principal value). One could extend this idea by integrating over the logarithm of $\phi$. This should give back a variant on the Cauchy integral theorem/residue theorem, but I am still working this out.

Edit: As mentioned in the commments, any path over invertible elements can be rewritten as a multiplicative path. I should have formulated my statement differently. Instead of analysing multiplicative paths, I am more interested in the multiplicative parametrisation of a path (if it exists).

Comment: What do you mean by the elements being infinitesimally close to something?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Let $\alpha(t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}[G]^{\times}$ be any path consisting of invertible elements. Then you can think of $\alpha(1)$ as having been obtained from $\alpha(0)$ by multiplying $\alpha(0)$ by, say, first $\alpha(1/n)$, then $\alpha(2/n) \alpha(1/n)^{-1}$, then $\alpha(3/n) \alpha(2/n)^{-1}$, and so on for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So it seems to me that every path is multiplicative, if I've understood you correctly. Also, I don't see where you're using the fact that you're working in a group algebra.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, the group algebra inherits a metric from the underlying vector space.

@QiaochuYuan Indeed, any such path is multiplicative. I was wondering more about some of the questions one could answer with such a multiplicative parametrisation. Should have worded that more clearly. 

For example, the function $\phi$ `integrated' over the path has some nice properties, such as that it depends only on its beginning and endpoint. This is also an example that only works for group algebras, since only there is $\phi$ defined.

Comment: Having a metric does not mean that it makes sense to use the term infinitesimal.